# SQL get percentage column group by values sub-select wrong value

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with the following data, which is already grouped by Content and State:

```
| Content | State | Count |
| -------- | -------------- | ---|
| Content1    | Skipped            | 14|
| Content1   | Finished            | 28|
| Content2    | Skipped            |11|
| Content2    | Finished           |28|
| Content3   | Finished            |28|
| Content3   | Unknown           | 10|
```

I want to get the number of times the content has been started (aka either skipped or finished) and also the percentage of completion (number of completions over total number of times the content was started)

So from the above table, my expected result would be:

```
| Content | StartedCount | %Finished |
| -------- | -------------- | ---|
| Content1    | 52           | 66.7%|
| Content2    | 39           |71.8%|
| Content3   | 28          |100%|
```

This is the query I tried, but the sub-select isn't returning correct percentages:

```
select t1.*, 
(select count(*) 
from ContentTable t2 
where t2.State = 'Finished' 
and t2.Content = t1.Content) / t1.count 
from ContentTable t1 
where t1.State != 'Unknown';
```

So I separated the values to check them individually, and this is what I'm getting:

```
select t1.*, 
(select count(*) 
from ContentTable t2 
where t2.State = 'Finished' 
and t2.Content = t1.Content) as comp 
from ContentTable t1 
where t1.State != 'Unknown';
```

When the above query is run, the total for 'Finished' isn't correct:

```
| Content | Comp|
| -------- | -------|
| Content1    | 2   |
| Content2    | 2   |
```

So then I tried:

```
select t1.*, 
(select sum(t2.count) 
from ContentTable t2 
where t2.State = 'Finished' 
and t2.Content = t1.Content) as comp 
from ContentTable t1 
where t1.State != 'Unknown';
```

This time it summed up everything regardless of the conditions from the subselect:

```
| Content | Comp |
| -------- | ---------|
| Content1    | 56     |
| Content2    | 56    |
```

I'm not sure why the sub-select isn't working and could use some assistance, thanks.

**EDIT**:
So based on the comments I tried using the avg() function, but still getting incorrect ratios, also I can't use count(*) because the table is already grouped by so I had to use sum(count) to get the values:

```
select Content, 
sum(Count) as cnt, 
avg(case when State = 'Finished' then 1.0 else 0 end) as finished_ratio from ContentTable 
where State != 'Unknown' 
group by Content;
```

Yields:

```
| Content | Cnt       | FinishedRatio |
| -------- | ---------| ----|
| Content1    | 48    | 50% |
| Content2    | 39    | 50% |
```

**EDIT 2**:
I was able to get it to work using sum():

```
select Content, 
sum(Count) as cnt, 
SUM(case when State = 'Finished' then Count else 0 end)/sum(Count) as finished_ratio from ContentTable 
where State != 'Unknown' 
group by Content;
```

Yields:

```
| Content | Cnt       | FinishedRatio |
| -------- | ---------| ----|
| Content1    | 48    | 67% |
| Content2    | 39    | 72% |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation - `avg()` comes handy for this:

```
select content, 
    avg(case when state in ('Skipped', 'Finished') then 100.0 else 0 end) as percent_finished
from mytable
group by content
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select content, count(*) as num_rows,
       avg(case when state = 'Finished' then 1.0 else 0 end) as finished_ratio
from ContentTable t2 
group by content;
```